# weird variable hoisting in javascript

Tags: javascript

so we know that variables declared with the var keyword are hoisted and if we try to access their value before they have been initialized we get undefined. However, In the code below logging the name variable logs the function and not undefined why ?

```js
console.log(name);
console.log(lol);

var name = function(args = "Hello World"){
    console.log(args)
}

var lol = function(args = "Hello world") {
    console.log(args)
}
```

the output is

```
function(args = "Hello World"){
    console.log(args)
}
```

and

```
main.js:57 undefined
```

why isnt name variable undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window which is the root scope already has a name property. Try the following and look at the output in your console. If you click the link the page that opens has MyWin as the output for name.

HTML (test.html)

```
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="test.html" target="MyWin">Click me!</a>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript (test.js)

```
console.log("name", name);
console.log("notname", notname);
console.log("lol", lol);


var notname = function (args = "Hello World") {
    console.log(args)
}

var lol = function (args = "Hello world") {
    console.log(args)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code

```js
console.log(test);

var test = function(args = "Hello World"){
    console.log(args)
}
```

This will return `undefined` [because only declarations are hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#Only_declarations_are_hoisted). That is, your code after *hoisting* will be

```js
var test;
console.log(test);

test = function(args = "Hello World"){
    console.log(args)
}
```

Comment: i know about this. What i dont understand is why name is not undefined.

Comment: copy the html from https://pastebin.com/JbL89E6m and open it in your browser to see this

Answer (score 0):

I think you should logging like that why you confused.

```js
console.log(name);
console.log(lol);

var name = function(args = "Hello World"){
    console.log(args)
}

var lol = function(args = "Hello world") {
    console.log(args)
}

console.log(name);
console.log(lol);
```

Comment: copy the html from https://pastebin.com/JbL89E6m and open it in your browser to see this